# Sudo scapy not working on virtualenv

Tags: python, ubuntu, sudo, scapy

Just started messing around with scapy in my virutalenv, but I cant run 'sudo scapy' in it.  I am getting:

```
sudo: scapy: command not found
```

If I just run scapy, when I try to send a simple packet

```
send(IP(dst="www.google.com"/ICMP())
```

I am getting permissionError operation permitted.  How do I get it to work?

Comment: `sudo` is the superuser and it might influence the way your applications work, for example `sudo` reset the environment.

Comment: Shouldn't pip be used in this case?

Answer (score 7):

As indicated in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44314951, you need to run *scapy* with *sudo* privileges in order to be able to use certain functionality. In this case, sending a packet.

Given that you want to use the *scapy* version in your virtual environment, you need to provide the full path to the *scapy* binary in your virtual environment in order for it to work. You can get this path while your virtual environment is active by executing:

```
$ which scapy
/home/someuser/.pythonenvs/test_scapy/bin/scapy
```

Then run again scapy using the full path:

```
$ sudo /home/someuser/.pythonenvs/test_scapy/bin/scapy
```

Comment: Or...  
`(activate your virutalenv)`  
`sudo $(which scapy)`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with VirtualEnv, but I've had the same problem on Ubuntu 16.04. Turns out, installing it through

> sudo apt-get install scapy

was what fixed it for me. Before that I installed it through pip install.

Answer (score 2):

***it works!***

assuming you've `virtualenv` installed.

```
virtualenv --python=3.8 packet_sniffer_env38
source packet_sniffer_env38/bin/activate
pip install scapy
```

Now you can run a program using scapy

```
sudo ./packet_sniffer_env38/bin/python <your_program_using_scapy>.py
```

[you can have a look at the working use of scapy python package with virtualenv](https://github.com/aakriti0fnu/Develope-a-packet-sniffer)!

**Optional!**

**has nothing to do with the virtual environment**, depending on your OS you might need to install `tcpdump` on ubuntu you've to `sudo apt-get install tcpdump`, and then you need to ensure that the promiscuous mode is enabled for an interface you're using.