# sudo pipenv run issue

Tags: python, linux, pipenv

I am trying to use scapy and netfilterqueue with python 3.6.1. I created an environment with these installed.. as netfilterqueue will not work on python 3.9.

When I try to run my script:
`pipenv run python3 test.py`

it runs in the correct environment but I get:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

When I try to run with sudo: `sudo pipenv run python3 test.py`

I get:

```
Warning: Python 3.6.1 was not found on your system…
You can specify specific versions of Python with:
  $ pipenv --python path/to/python
```

I've verified my libraries are correctly installed on the environment but am just not sure how to pass permissions to run a script. Thanks!

```
──(kali㉿bad)-[~/Desktop/env]
└─$ pipenv shell                  
Launching subshell in virtual environment...
 . /home/kali/.local/share/virtualenvs/env-_HkHVbK0/bin/activate
WARNING: `pyenv init -` no longer sets PATH.
Run `pyenv init` to see the necessary changes to make to your configuration.
┌──(kali㉿bad)-[~/Desktop/env]
└─$  . /home/kali/.local/share/virtualenvs/env-_HkHVbK0/bin/activate
                                                                                           
┌──(env-_HkHVbK0)(kali㉿bad)-[~/Desktop/env]
└─$ python3
Python 3.6.1 (default, May 12 2021, 17:05:21) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import scapy
>>> import netfilterqueue
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/home/kali/.pyenv/versions/3.6.1/lib/python36.zip', '/home/kali/.pyenv/versions/3.6.1/lib/python3.6', '/home/kali/.pyenv/versions/3.6.1/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/kali/.local/share/virtualenvs/env-_HkHVbK0/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
>>>
```

Comment: How did you set up the project before running `pipenv run python3 test.py`?

Comment: I used `pipenv install <libraries>` , which I believe makes the environment too if it doesn't already exist.. and that seemed to work. Then I changed the versions of python manually in the two pipefile's in the environment folder.

Comment: Take a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44304988/permissionerror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted/44314951

Comment: thanks but my issue is it won't let me run the script with sudo.

Answer (score 0):

I did have similar issue.
I managed to solved by running the virtual environment's Python executable with sudo. For example if your virtualenv is ./AwesomeProject, then you could run sudo ./AwesomeProject/bin/python  to use the script with the virtualenv with root privileges.

To find where your the virtual environment's Python executable (Ex: ./AwesomeProject/bin/python), inside the virtual env run

```
whereis python
```

more info:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/234758/how-to-use-a-python-virtualenv-with-sudo